# How to style long HTML code

Tags: html, css

I have a very long HTML line that goes like this:

```
<p>ABC , DEFG , HI , JKLMN </p>
```

And I want to style each portion of letters. Is it possible to target them? The length is not always the same and it can change, but the `,` will always separate them.

I can't modify HTML to include classes.

Comment: Not unless these words or "portion of letters" have selectors for CSS to target. Consider exploring javascript methods to string replace (`.replace()`) or split the string at the commas (`,`) and wrap the preceding or following words in elements to target with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either javascript or jquery to do the same.

Here is a working **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sq8cyjt2/)**

**HTML**

```
<p>ABC , DEFG , HI , JKLMN </p>
```

**Javscript**

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
console.log(p[0].innerHTML);
var texts = p[0].innerHTML.split(',');
console.log(texts);
for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
  var className;
  if (i%2 === 0) {
    className = 'red';
  } else {
    className = 'blue';
  }
  texts[i] = texts[i].replace(texts[i], '<span class="' + className + '">' + texts[i] + '</span>');
}
console.log(texts);
console.log(texts.join(", "));
p[0].innerHTML = texts.join(", ");
```

**Css**

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```